# executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) -- mysql with Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, mysql-python

fields is => [u'sender', u'timestamp', u'number', u'mms', u'datetime', u'text', u'id']

dataList is  => [(False, 1475565742761L, u'VM-449100', False, u'2016-10-04 12:52:22 GMT+05:30', u'Some text here', 1276)]

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """INSERT INTO messages """+str(tuple(fields))+""" VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """,dataList

    cursor.executemany(query)
```

On executing the above code i am getting error => executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: That error message is pretty clear. You're not giving it enough arguments. What's your question?

Comment: then just tell me how to insert multiple rows in mysql using python

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `executemany` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql query and parameters should be passed as single arguments. You are currently passing a tuple instead. I would change it to:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """INSERT INTO messages (""" + ",".join(fields) + """) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """

cursor.executemany(query, dataList)
```

Note that `query` is now a string, and I have used `join` to convert the list of fields to a comma separated string. If you use `str(tuple(fields))` you may end up with unwanted `u''` prefixes.